# How to double the size of a picture

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I've written and it works just fine. But there is a small problem in it. When I click on the zoom button, not only must the last hidden picture appear but also, its size must increase (double the normal size).
In my code, only the picture appears but its size doesn't change. Please help me with that, I don't know how to do it.

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img.images');
var displayCount = 0;
var hideCount = 0;
document.getElementById('display').onclick = function() {
  if (hideCount < images.length) {
    images[hideCount].style.display = 'none';
    hideCount++;
  } else {
    images[displayCount].style.display = 'block';
    displayCount++;
    if (displayCount === images.length) {
      displayCount = 0;
      hideCount = 0;
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('zoombtn').onclick = function() {
  if (hideCount > 0) {
    images[hideCount - 1].style.display = 'block';
    hideCount--;
  } else {
    images[12].style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.botton {
  height: 30px;
  width: 315px;
}

.table {
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="botton" ; id="display" ;>Display</button>
<button class="botton" ; id="zoombtn" ;>Zoom</button>
<br>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img SRC="IMG/blfy.gif" ALT="Butterflies" id="image-1" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img SRC="IMG/eye.gif" ALT="Eye" id="image-2" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img SRC="IMG/wave.gif" ALT="Wave" id="image-3" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/jungle.gif" ALT="Jungle" id="image-4" class="images" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/bridge.gif" ALT="Bridge" id="image-5" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/duck.gif" ALT="Duck" id="image-6" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/egg.gif" ALT="Eggs" id="image-7" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/aurora.gif" ALT="Aurora" id="image-8" class="images" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/it.gif" ALT="Technology" id="image-9" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/hill.gif" ALT="Hills" id="image-10" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/string.gif" ALT="strings" id="image-11" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/vegi.gif" ALT="vegetables" id="image-12" class="images" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>
```

Comment: Please try to be more clear about what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: here is what i want:

when i click on the zoom button, the last hidden picture appears again.
but this isn't enough. i want that picture to appear and its size to increase(double the normal size)

Answer (score 0):

```
<img onload="double(this.id);" name="bigPic" id="bigPic" src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/bd294ce7ff4c43b6aad4aa4169fb819b.jpg" height="1000" width="1000"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LFPWt/
See this link i hope it will useful to you

Comment: the problem is that images keep growing after many click on display and they don't go back to the normal size, i tried to fixed it like this:
but it didn't work

Comment: <script>

var images = document.querySelectorAll('img.images');
var displayCount = 0;
var hideCount = 0;
document.getElementById('display').onclick = function() {
  if (hideCount < images.length) {
    images[hideCount].style.display = 'none';
    hideCount++;
  } else {
    images[displayCount].width = auto;
    images[displayCount].height = auto;
    images[displayCount].style.display = 'block';
    displayCount++;
    if (displayCount ===  images.length) {
      displayCount = 0;
      hideCount = 0;
    }
  }
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access its `width` and `height`. This will double them. Do the same for the 12 part of it. (Also, that part probably can use some work.)

```
images[hideCount-1].width *= 2;
images[hideCount-1].height *= 2;
```

Comment: the problem with this code is that the pictures do not go back to the normal size for next runs

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to double the size of the image that appears when you click zoom, as well as retain its original size when you display/zoom it further. To double the image size, simply `*= 2` the `height` and `width` of the image. To revert it back to the original size I take a look at the `setImageSize` function. It's not an optimal solution but it should give you a general idea of how you can do it.

Take a look at the code below, hopefully it accomplishes what you want:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img.images');
var displayCount = 0;
var hideCount = 0;

function setImageSize(){
  var originalWidth = 200;
  var originalHeight = 200;
  for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
    images[i].width = originalWidth;
    images[i].height = originalHeight;
  }
}

document.getElementById('display').onclick = function() {
  if (hideCount < images.length) {
    setImageSize();
    images[hideCount].style.display = 'none';
    hideCount++;
  } else {
    images[displayCount].style.display = 'block';
    displayCount++;
    if (displayCount ===  images.length) {
      displayCount = 0;
      hideCount = 0;
    }
  }
}
</script>
<script>
document.getElementById('zoombtn').onclick = function () {
if (hideCount > 0) {
   setImageSize();
   images[hideCount-1].style.display= 'block';
   images[hideCount-1].height *=2;
   images[hideCount-1].width *=2;
   hideCount--;
   } else {
   images[12].style.display='block';
 }
}
```

```css
.botton {
  height: 30px;
  width: 315px;
}

.table {
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button class="botton";  id="display";>Display</button>
<button class="botton";  id="zoombtn";>Zoom</button>
<br>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img SRC="https://erconsult.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-200x200.png" ALT="Butterflies" id="image-1" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img SRC="https://erconsult.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-200x200.png" ALT="Eye" id="image-2" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img SRC="https://erconsult.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-200x200.png" ALT="Wave" id="image-3" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="https://erconsult.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-200x200.png" ALT="Jungle" id="image-4" class="images" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="https://erconsult.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-200x200.png" ALT="Bridge" id="image-5" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="https://erconsult.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-200x200.png" ALT="Duck" id="image-6" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="https://erconsult.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-200x200.png" ALT="Eggs" id="image-7" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="https://erconsult.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-200x200.png" ALT="Aurora" id="image-8" class="images" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="https://erconsult.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-200x200.png" ALT="Technology" id="image-9" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="https://erconsult.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-200x200.png" ALT="Hills" id="image-10" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="https://erconsult.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-200x200.png" ALT="strings" id="image-11" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="https://erconsult.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/placeholder-200x200.png" ALT="vegetables" id="image-12" class="images" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img.images');
var displayCount = 0;
var hideCount = 0;
document.getElementById('display').onclick = function() {
  if (hideCount < images.length) {
    images[hideCount].style.display = 'none';
    zoomOut(images[hideCount]);
    hideCount++;
  } else {
    images[displayCount].style.display = 'block';
    zoomOut(images[displayCount]);
    displayCount++;
    if (displayCount ===  images.length) {
      displayCount = 0;
      hideCount = 0;
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('zoombtn').onclick = function () {
 if (hideCount > 0) {
      images[hideCount-1].style.display= 'block';
      zoomIn(images[hideCount-1]);
      hideCount--;
    } else {
      images[11].style.display='block';
      zoomIn(images[11]);
  }
}

function zoomIn(zElement) {
  var element = document.getElementById(zElement.id);
  element.style.transform = "scale(2)";
  //element.style.width *= 2;
}

function zoomOut(zElement) {
  var element = document.getElementById(zElement.id);
  element.style.transform = "scale(1)";
}
```

Comment: i think its the right idea but the code doesn't completely work and i can't figure the problem

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: when all the pictures disappear, and when i click the display button for the 13th time the pictures do not appear anymore

Comment: Please change "" element.style.transform = "scale(0)"  ====  element.style.transform = "scale(1)";  see updated my answer.